# Volume control after loop as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem with my code. The code works great with one exception, if I have pressed the mute-button and the animation loops, it's always back to volume = 1. How can it loop without always going back to volume = 1?

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var songURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Lyd/jetpass.mp3");
var channel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var volumeAdjust:SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
mute1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteLyd);
volumeAdjust.volume = 1;
mySound.load(songURL);
channel1.soundTransform = volumeAdjust;
channel1 = mySound.play();

function muteLyd(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(volumeAdjust.volume == 1){
    volumeAdjust.volume = 0;
} 
else {
  volumeAdjust.volume = 1;
}
channel1.soundTransform = volumeAdjust;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out this code solves the problem:

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound();
var songURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("Lyd/jetpass.mp3");
var channel1:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
mute1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, muteLyd);
unmute1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, unMuteLyd);

mySound.load(songURL);
channel1 = mySound.play();

function muteLyd(evt:MouseEvent){
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(0);
    unmute1.visible = true;
    mute1.visible = false;
}

function unMuteLyd (evt:MouseEvent){
    SoundMixer.soundTransform = new SoundTransform(1);
    unmute1.visible = false;
    mute1.visible = true;
}
```